# Regex: Finding non-duplicate characters

Tags: regex

I have a string of letters:

```
'AAACDDBBK'
```

I want to match only characters  which only repeat once, so for instance: `C` and `K`. I know brackets `{}` can be used to specify the number of matches you want, but that does not appear to be working for me.

```
str = 'AAACDDBBK'
regex = /[a-zA-Z]{1}/
str.match(regex)
>>>["A"]
```

How do I filter characters with more than one occurrence?

Comment: what language are you using?

Answer (score 3):

You can use a regex like this to find the duplicates:

```
(.).*\1
```

Then you can use a replace over your main string by an empty string, so your resulting string will have all the characters non duplicated

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/lG6rU4/1)**

The `substitution section` contains your resulting string having the non duplicated characters:

[image]

Btw, if you just want to find the non duplicated letters you can change the regex to:

```
([A-Za-z]).*\1
```

This solution, works for consecutive characters but if you can have duplicated characters then you should use another solution. What I'd do is to split your string by characters and add them into a map, then store for each character the count for their ocurrences. So, there you have another approach without regex.

Comment: That won't work .e.g `"AAPAACDDBBK".replace(/([A-Za-z]).*\1/g, "");`

Comment: Yeah, when I try this I get "["AAA", "A"]"

Answer (score 0):

With Ruby or PHP you can use this kind of pattern:

```
(?:(.)\1+)*\K(.|$)
```

The idea is to find a unique character eventually preceded by one or several repeated character sequences, then to remove them using `\K` from the whole match result and to match the searched unique character with a simple `.` or the end of the string.

[demo](http://rubular.com/r/0O6Ptjslzq)

An other possible way consists to use an alternation that begins with repeated characters:

```
(?:(.)\1+)+|(.)
```

not repeated characters are in the capture group 2.

Comment: I'm struggling against this, also tried you regex doesn't work [check it here](https://regex101.com/r/vL0kP4/1)

Comment: @Fede: It seems that you haven't see that my approach consists to match (see capture group 2 for the result) not to replace anything.

Comment: @Fede: In my opinion the OP want only to avoid consecutive characters, and to be clear, if it isn't the case (so, non duplicate characters whatever the position in the string), it is no more a job for regex.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you. Just commented since I learned a lot from you

Answer (score 0):

This is a workaround for not having advanced PCRE features in Javascript:

```
str = 'AAACDDBBK'
str.replace(new RegExp(str.match(/([A-Z])(?=.*?\1)/ig).join('|'), "g"), "");
//=> CK

str="AAPAACDDBBK";
str.replace(new RegExp(str.match(/([A-Z])(?=.*?\1)/ig).join('|'), "g"), "");
//=> PCK
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution of Federico Piazza above works.
In Ruby, it would look like this:

```
st = 'aaabbceeefgh'

# All non-repeated characters:
st.gsub(/(.).*\1/,'') # => "cfgh"

# First non-repeated characters:
st.gsub(/(.).*\1/,'')[0] # => "c"
```