# Find longest sub string within non repeated string

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce

I need to find the longest sub string within a string.

```
const string = "aassqwertybbvvqwertyuivv";

const a = string.split("").reduce((previousValue, currentValue, currentIndex, array) => {
    let str = ""
    if (previousValue !== currentValue) {
    str = currentValue + str;
  }
  return str;
}, "");
console.log(a)
```

Here the answer shoule be 8 (qwertyui).

It just returns me the last string

Comment: Use RegEx: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29480612/3098783

Comment: *"I need to find the longest sub string"* - based on what ? What is considered sub string in your case ?

Comment: @ths string between two consecutive alphabets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?!

```js
const s = "aassqwertybbvvqwertyuivv"

const longest = (max, c) => c.length > max.length ? c : max

const maxs = s.replace(/(.)\1+/g, ' ')
  .split(' ')
  .reduce(longest, '')
  
console.log(maxs)
```